# Find a differential equation describing family of curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

My family of curves looks like this:
$\{y=c_1e^{\lambda_1x}+c_2e^{\lambda_2x}\}$

My teacher told me to consider this:

$\frac{d}{dx}e^{\lambda_1x}=\lambda_1e^{\lambda_1x}$

So taking $y_1=e^{\lambda_1x}$ we obtain $\frac{d}{dx}y_1=\lambda_1y_1$.

What means that $y_1$ is an eigenvector of $\frac{d}{dx}$, am I right?

What's also means that $(\frac{d}{dx}-\lambda_1I)y_1=0$
But that's really strange to me and I don't know what to do with it next. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you differentiate one more time. That family of curves will satisfy a second order differential equation.